# Unable to print from WebBrowser and browser.Document is null

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` that is used to display a temporary pdf document. The document is constructed by the program and works fine in a normal browser.

The file is loaded by calling `browser.Navigate()` and the pdf displays fine in the actual application window, but when calling `browser.Print()` triggers an error:

[image]

I've also noticed that `browser.Document` remains null, even during the callback of document completed:

```
browser.DocumentCompleted += documentCompletedHandler;

... 

private void documentCompletedHandler(object sender,  WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs  e) {
 WebBrowser b = sender as WebBrowser;
  Console.WriteLine("Loaded: " + b.Url.AbsoluteUri); // Correct path.
  // b.Document == null here and everywhere else.
}
```

XAML:

```
...
<WindowsFormsHost>
  <wf:WebBrowser x:Name="browser" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
...
```

Comment: You will always read pdf files or other web pages as well?

Comment: Only pdf files, its used as a preview before print

Comment: So you will require your users to have Adobe PDF reader installed to use this functionality?

Comment: I though that the browser used some embedded pdf viewer unless adobe reader was installed, but that doesn't sound like its the case?

Comment: Have your tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057446/how-to-print-a-pdf-file-displayed-in-the-wpf-webbrowser-control

Comment: Yes,  the Document property remains null, as stated in the question

Comment: An alternative may be to use a library to convert the PDF to a Bitmap and print that.

Comment: Relying on Adobe Reader is a grave mistake.  Lots of PDF viewers and printing libraries out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a PDF file in your WPF application you are using the WinForms WebBrowser control, hosted using the WindowsFormsHost component for WPF so you can then use the Adobe PDF Reader DirectX control for Internet Explorer in your WPF application.

Way too many layers, don't you think? This is prone to errors so let's try to simplify the system:

First of all, WPF comes with a native WebBrowser control (after .NET 3.5 SP1) so you could use the control directly avoiding the WindowsFormsHost altogether.

```
<WebBrowser Source="C:\SomeFile.pdf" />
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/web-browser-control-in-wpf/

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-webbrowser-control/

This may already solve your problem but using an embedded browser that will then use the Adobe Reader Active X might not be the best solution because it will require that the user has Adobe PDF Reader and the Adobe PDF ActiveX Reader installed as well as a working version of IE.

One solution would be to use WindowsFormsHost as you already do but instead of using a WebBrowser, using the Adobe PDF Reader Active X for Windows Forms:

https://wpfpdfviewer.codeplex.com/
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380019/Using-Adobe-Reader-in-a-WPF-app

This will work fine and you won't have problems to print but again in order to work, users will need to have Adobe PDF Reader installed in their system.

The best solution would be to use a control that doesn't have any external dependencies, for that, there are many high quality commercial components (search for DevExpress or Telerik PDF viewer controls).

If you want to try something open source I found this but never used it myself:

https://github.com/reliak/moonpdf

Comment: I didn't use any of the method proposed, but I took the heart of the post as advice, i.e. simplify the layers and try not to depend on things needed to be installed. I already use a library for building the PDF and that have a control provided. This control works and I will use this instead of the webbrowser :)